# Mocha how to remove exception stack traces from the console

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I dont want to show exception stack traces in the tests.
I am testing a negative conditions, so they are planned to fail.
How can i suppress them or emove them

Comment: Whay don't you catch them instead of suppress the stacktrace?

Comment: i dont want to catch them. I want to suppress them. They are planned errors.

Comment: If they are planned then you have to make the test pass, thus catch them. With `expect.js` you can write `expect(fn).to.throwError();`. With other assertion libraries there are similar helpers.